# Factory Girl has_one through relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I am having great difficulty setting up Factory Girl to mimic my model associations. I believe the problem is that I am not setting up the "User has one plan through subscription" association up correctly. Any help is greatly appreciated!

I am getting this error:

```
 Failure/Error: let(:plan) {FactoryGirl.create(:plan, :user => user) }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `user=' for #<Plan:0x007fd836a1a340>
```

My models are as follows:

#### User.rb

```
has_one :subscription
has_one :plan, :through => :subscription
has_many :projects
```

#### Project.rb

```
belongs_to :user
```

#### Plan.rb

```
has_many :subscriptions
```

#### Subscription.rb

```
belongs_to :plan
belongs_to :user
```

And my FactoryGirl code

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :user do

    first_name "Joel"
    last_name "Brewer"
    email { "#{first_name}.#{last_name}@example.com".downcase }
    password "booyabooya"
    password_confirmation "booyabooya"
    user_type "entrepreneur"
  end

  factory :plan do |f|
    f.association :user
    f.plan_type "entrepreneur"
    f.plan_level "bronze"
    f.user_project_limit '1'
 end

  factory :subscription do |f|
    f.association :user
    f.association :plan
    f.stripe_card_token "Test card token"
    f.stripe_customer_token "Test customer token"
    f.email "joel.brewer1@example.com"
  end

  factory :project do
    title "Sample Project"
    user
  end
end
```

Comment: If you already know the source of your problem, why are you not fixing it? You just did not define the `user` relation in your plan, so rails can't figure that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The undefined method error on `user=` is because you don't have a `user` field defined for `Plan` but have an `association :user` in your `:plan` factory. Assuming that you only want plans to be associated with users through subscriptions, you need to take the `association :user` out of our `:plan` factory.

I'm not completely clear on all the options available to you for handling the situation you have, but assuming you're intent with the factory call is to create a subscription for the specified user at the same time you create the plan, then the following (untested) approach should work, taken from https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md

```
factory :plan do
  plan_type "entrepreneur"
  plan_level "bronze"
  user_project_limit '1'

  factory :plan_with_subscription do
    ignore { user }
    after(:create) do |plan, evaluator|
      create(:subscription, plan: plan, user: evaluator.user)
    end
  end

end
```

You'll want to change your call to use `:plan_with_subscription` instead of `:plan` to cause the subscription to be created.

Comment: Hmm. I feel like this answer is close, however, I am still getting this error: `Failure/Error: let(:plan) {FactoryGirl.create(:plan, user: user) } NoMethodError: undefined method `user=` for #<Plan:0x..>

Comment: See updated answer with several changes. BTW, I'm not sure why you're including/using the formal parameter `f` in your factory definitions. I removed it in my update.

Comment: I followed your code, but I still receive this error: `Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.create(:plan_with_subscription, :user => user) undefined method user= for #<Plan...>` Here is a link to my factories.rb file: [link](https://gist.github.com/JahBrewski/8446767)

Comment: Seems to be working now that I added ignore user to the :plan factory. Check out my edit.

Comment: Sorry about that. I think you're absolutely right. I didn't see any edit from you, but I edited it myself with what I think was needed. Let me know.

Comment: Peter, you were close. I went ahead and submitted another edit. Hopefully you will see this one!

Comment: Ok, I saw both your edits now and see that they were both rejected. Before I change it, can you confirm that the change I proposed didn't work for you? The `ignore` shouldn't need to be within the outer block, since you're not calling `create :plan, ...`, you shouldn't need the `:user` argument and `{}` vs. `do end` shouldn't matter.